Gradle Build failing when updating Unity project to Android 14 (API 34)
When running my Unity (2020.1.14f1) project in Android Studio (Iguana 2023.2.1) I get the following error:

A problem occurred configuring project ':unityLibrary'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
org/gradle/api/plugins/MavenPlugin
Could not create task ':unityLibrary:mergeDebugJniLibFolders'.
> Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

I don't have a lot of knowledge of Gradle so I'm working in the dark to find a solution here.
I'm just trying to update my app to target Android 14 (API 34) and I'm running out of time to fix it before my app is taken off the store
